# AWS SQS Error - Message must be shorter than 262144 bytes - Laravel Queued Jobs

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, queue, amazon-sqs, jobs

So this one is puzzling our team at the moment and we can’t seem to get to the bottom of what is causing the error.

We’re currently getting the following error from AWS SQS only for one or two jobs.

```
Error executing "SendMessage" on "https://sqs.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/XXXXXXX/live"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: POST https://sqs.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/XXXXXXX/live resulted in a 400 Bad Request response:
<?xml version="1.0"?><ErrorResponse xmlns="http://queue.amazonaws.com/doc/2012-11-05/"><Error><Type>Sender</Type><Code>I (truncated...)
InvalidParameterValue (client): One or more parameters are invalid. Reason: Message must be shorter than 262144 bytes. - <?xml version="1.0"?><ErrorResponse xmlns="http://queue.amazonaws.com/doc/2012-11-05/"><Error><Type>Sender</Type><Code>InvalidParameterValue</Code><Message>One or more parameters are invalid. Reason: Message must be shorter than 262144 bytes.</Message><Detail/></Error><RequestId>bb68b4c1-15ec-5b47-bc89-efb2794f87d5</RequestId></ErrorResponse>
```

The error seems to indicate that the size of the job is too big however that is simply not the case. We have identified a job that seems to correspond with the times of the errors. The serialised payload looks something like the below. Clearly what is sent is not over 262144 bytes; it's extremely small.

The strange thing about it seems to be that the jobs do succeed so the jobs aren’t failing, they’re still processing correctly.

```json
'{"uuid":"9c63a7b7-f37f-4afa-bb5e-ca0f88e49c7e","displayName":"App\\\\Modules\\\\Tasks\\\\Listeners\\\\SendEmailNotifications","job":"Illuminate\\\\Queue\\\\CallQueuedHandler@call","maxTries":null,"maxExceptions":null,"failOnTimeout":false,"backoff":null,"timeout":null,"retryUntil":null,"data":{"commandName":"Illuminate\\\\Events\\\\CallQueuedListener","command":"O:36:\\"Illuminate\\\\Events\\\\CallQueuedListener\\":19:{s:5:\\"class\\";s:50:\\"App\\\\Modules\\\\Tasks\\\\Listeners\\\\SendEmailNotifications\\";s:6:\\"method\\";s:23:\\"handleEmailNotification\\";s:4:\\"data\\";a:1:{i:0;O:40:\\"App\\\\Modules\\\\Tasks\\\\Events\\\\LogCreatedEvent\\":4:{s:7:\\"tasklog\\";O:45:\\"Illuminate\\\\Contracts\\\\Database\\\\ModelIdentifier\\":4:{s:5:\\"class\\";s:34:\\"App\\\\Modules\\\\Tasks\\\\Models\\\\FvTaskLog\\";s:2:\\"id\\";i:217725;s:9:\\"relations\\";a:1:{i:0;s:6:\\"status\\";}s:10:\\"connection\\";s:3:\\"dev\\";}s:3:\\"url\\";s:26:\\"http:\\/\\/dev.laraclear.local\\";s:8:\\"database\\";s:3:\\"dev\\";s:6:\\"params\\";a:0:{}}}s:5:\\"tries\\";N;s:13:\\"maxExceptions\\";N;s:7:\\"backoff\\";N;s:10:\\"retryUntil\\";N;s:7:\\"timeout\\";N;s:17:\\"shouldBeEncrypted\\";b:0;s:3:\\"job\\";N;s:10:\\"connection\\";N;s:5:\\"queue\\";N;s:15:\\"chainConnection\\";N;s:10:\\"chainQueue\\";N;s:19:\\"chainCatchCallbacks\\";N;s:5:\\"delay\\";N;s:11:\\"afterCommit\\";N;s:10:\\"middleware\\";a:0:{}s:7:\\"chained\\";a:0:{}}"}}'
```

Comment: Same problem with https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/queued.html#queued when using implements FromQuery, ShouldQueue, WithCustomChunkSize. If the chunk zise is bigger than the results number it works. Wgen I set it to lower then it gives this error. Is it possible that the non FIFO queue is the reason?

Comment: Update if I put chunk size  for 20 rows of export it dies. If I put 2 it works...